# How do I execute a custom SQL script from a batch file?

Tags: batch, sql

Here is the script im using

sqlcmd -S.\host name
It returns 1>
here I enter the database name
it returs 2>
I type Go and hit enter
it returns "changed database context to database name"
THEN, I enter my custom sql script and hit enter.

I'm trying to figure out how to automat this so that I can drop a file on a desktop, run it, it executes the script.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you perhaps wanting to run a batch file that prompts the user to provide a database name, then use that user-provided response to run sqlcmd?

Comment: @Twisty I figured out my answer to that problem but ran into another within the same file. I used echo use databasename | sqlcmd -S.\database which returned "changed context to database name" exactly like I wanted it to. The next step I needed was to execute some sqlcommands now that the context was changed, but I can't get that last bit to execute. I'm new to this so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do: You want to automate sending commands to `sqlcmd`. If that's correct, do a Google search on "script sqlcmd". You need to write a script (a simple text file) that contains the commands you want to send sqlcmd, then run sqlcmd and tell it to run your script.

Comment: Ok so there's no way to just add the code into the batch file and not have a separate file it references the script from?  I'm trying to have a batch file that I can drop on a computer, execute it and then it deletes itself.

Comment: Actually, yes, it's possible to do all of this from a single batch file. If you edit your question to something like *How do I execute a custom SQL script from a batch file?* I can provide an answer. But first look at how to [run a script with sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files) so you understand the process better.

Comment: Ok. I changed the title and read the page.

Comment: OK--The question body needs to be edited as well. Others may wish to answer and it needs to be clear to all what you're after.

Comment: Body changed as well

Comment: Oh dear. I think I've not been clear enough. Please try to use the link I provided to create a script that you can run with SQLCMD. *Then* when you have that working, come back here and ask how to take that SQL script and automate it with a batch file. Unfortunately your question presently doesn't have any of this context and risks being closed as being "too broad".  I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I already have the script. I know how to execute everything by typing it in manually. I just want to automate it.

Comment: Excellent. Your question needs to reflect this. The synopsis might be *"I have the following script I execute with this command....How can I automate [be specific about what **exactly** you need to automate]?"*

Comment: I've changed it to explain the manual process and then hopefully asked the right question.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use `SQLCMD -S <SQLInstanceName> -d <DBName>` syntax to specify the DB name to use. If you are running a query with `-Q` then add `USE <DBName>` before you run query logic and same with a script have `USE <DBName>` run before running the rest of the SQL statements. I've done this many many times so if I can do it then you can do it.